# Fill Datatable with list member, if it matches a SQL select

Tags: sql, list, select, datatable

I have a list of numbers and names. I would like to search through a database and find if the number matches my sql select. if it does I need to fill it to the datatable along with the name. Then foreach row in the datatable write that to another list. I'm having trouble filling the name to the datatable as well because I'm not using it in the SQl select as a parameter.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try {
    using (SqlConnection conn = getconnection()) {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000;
        string select = @"SELECT NBR
                    FROM People
                    where ID in (15,17) and NBR=Nbr and ACCEPTED=0";

        foreach (Fields f in Members) {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nbr", f.nbr);
            cmd.CommandText = select;
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //if f.nbr matches sql select fill it to datatable how can I fill dt with f.name as well?
            adapt.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
        Fields f1 = new Fields();
        f1.nbr= Convert.ToInt64(row["NBR"]); 
        // f1.name=Convert.ToString(row["Name"]????
        Not.Add(f1);
    }
```

Comment: So why aren't you including the name in the query?

Comment: because that sql table does not have a name field only a nbr field

Comment: In your select string can you do a join to the table that does have the name?

Comment: Why are you doing this is C#? You should be able to build an update and or select query and get the sql server do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @DaleM is completely correct. There is no sense to have this kind of embeeded T-SQL code on C#. Instead, you should implement a solution containing stored procedures being called when needed and performing much more faster than doing it from your app. Additionally, take into account having hardcoded values on your app makes maintenability really hard. Hope my tips helps.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 string select = @"SELECT NBR, Name
                    FROM People
                    where ID in (15,17) and NBR=@Nbr and ACCEPTED=0";
```